# HostNotFoundError error when running 'npm start' on Node.js server - React Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js, webserver

**Description of the problem:**

I'm working on a React project and when trying to run `npm start` on the server folder, I get the following error:

```
HostNotFoundError [SequelizeHostNotFoundError]: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined

Problem Details:

The project consists of three important files in the server folder: db.js, index.js and server.js. I think the error might be related to one of these files, but I'm not sure which one.

I leave you the link to the project's github repository:
Link to the Repository: https://github.com/Mateo-mh/PI-countries

Steps to Reproduce the Error:

1) I navigate to the server folder in my project.
2) I run the npm start command in the terminal.

Complete Error Message:

     [0] HostNotFoundError [SequelizeHostNotFoundError]: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined
     [0] parent: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined
     [0] at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
     [0] errno: -3008,
     [0] code: 'ENOTFOUND',
     [0] syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
     [0] hostname: 'undefined'
     [0] },
     [0] original: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined
     [0] at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
     [0] errno: -3008,
     [0] code: 'ENOTFOUND',
     [0] syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
     [0] hostname: 'undefined'
     [0] }
     [0] }

Tools and Technologies Version:

Node.js: v18.16.1
sequelize: v6.31.1

I would greatly appreciate your help in resolving this issue. Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting this error and how I can fix it?
```

Comment: Can you show your sequelize code where you connect to the database?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is issue in **db.js** where you had define your database cred, as according to error your database cred is wrong.